# WSDL generated proxy class

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, alfresco

I have a question regarding the generated proxy class for a web service. Basically I've tried to add a web service reference to my solution but i couldn't because of a missing discorvery file, so I did as a lot of ppl said on the internet by generating a proxy class with WSDL and then instatiate it and use it.

So basically i got a nice proxy class, but how do i used it, of course i can instantieate it and call the methods BUT how is it now connected to the actual web service on some server on internet?

If you look at the wsdl file, you will find for example:

```
 <wsdl:service name="AuthenticationService">
  <wsdl:documentation>Provides simple authentication capability.</wsdl:documentation> 
   <wsdl:port binding="auth:AuthenticationServiceSoapBinding" name="AuthenticationService">
  <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

It redirects to localhost of the requested webserver etc etc ...

But when in my class i have this as constructor with 'localhost' url, but the web service is running on other server so yeah it is normal that i'll not be able to connect.

```
public AuthenticationService() {
    this.Url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService";
 }
```

But how can I now correctly use this now?

Should i set this url to the original url of wsdl file? 
Something like that: `http://internetserver:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService.wsdl` ? Doing that returns me wsdl file back but not the results and i get error. Trying something else i get 404 as a result ....

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is limited but I added a web service reference once for Apple's GSX service. It added the following to my web.config which I assume is how the client object connects:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://gsxws2.apple.com/gsx-ws/services/emea/iphone" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GsxWSEmeaIPhoneBinding" contract="AppleGSX.GsxWSEmeaIPhonePort" name="GsxWSEmeaIPhonePort"/>
</client>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to connect to the service running on another server then you will need to change the URL behaviour to dynamic - see this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

This will allow you to reference the same web service running on a different URL by changing your config file.